# I cannot select anything from my form

Tags: html, css, forms

I am currently experimenting on forms and right now I have a problem, I cannot select anything on the form(inputs, options and checkboxes) and I don't know why, I cannot determine the problem, the code below works fine in Firefox but it doesn't work on Chrome, what is the problem here? am I missing something?

The CSS,

```
body {
    font: 90%/1 "Myriad Pro", Frutiger, "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans", "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;}

form {
    width: 40em;}

legend {
    font-weight: bold;}

fieldset {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #f5f5f5;}

label {
    width: 10em;
    float: left;
    clear: left;}

div {
    margin: 1em 0;} 

.short {
    width: 3em;}

.hide {
    width: 0;
    text-indent: -9999999999em;}

/* Favorite Color Fieldset Styles */

#favcolor {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10em;
    float: left;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1em;}

.col {
    margin: 0;
    width: 8em;
    float: left;}

.col div {
    margin: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0.4em;}

.col label {
    float: none;}
```

And the markup,

```
<form action="#" method="get">
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Personal Information</legend>
 <div>
 <label>Place of Birth</label>
  <select>
   <option value="america">America</option>
   <option value="philippines">Philippines</option>
   <option value="japan">Japan</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div>
 <label>Date of Birth</label>
 <label class="hide">Month of Birth</label>
 <label class="hide">Year of Birth</label>
 <input type="text" class="short" />
 <select>
  <option>January</option>
  <option>February</option>
  <option>March</option>
 </select>
 <input type="text" class="short" />
 </div>
  <fieldset id="favcolor">
   <h2>Favorite Color</h2>
   <div class="col">
    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="red" value="red" />Red</label>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="orange" value="orang" />Orange</label>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="yellow" value="yellow" />Yellow</label>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="green" value="green" />Green</label>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="blue" value="blue" />Blue</label>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="indigo" value="indigo" />Indigo</label>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="violet" value="violet" />Violet</label>
    </div>

    <div>
     <label><input type="checkbox" name="pink" value="pink" />Pink</label>
    </div>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The issue is caused by the `.hide` CSS. Removing it makes everything works properly.

Comment: How does it do that exactly? if you don't mind explaining. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Those `<label>`s needs `for` attributes. http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by this:

```
.hide {
    width: 0;
    text-indent: -9999999999em;
}
```

Replace it with:

```
.hide {
    width: 0;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
```

and it should work fine. [**(Example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/jemguzxh/)

<del>However, **hiding elements** by shifting them to an off-screen location **isn't exactly the best practice**. It's bettter to use other methods like `visibility: hidden;` or `display: none;` to hide elements.</del>

Comment: Thank you so much for the response, but if I can ask one more question. Why exactly does changing the numbers to only 4 make a difference? Thank's again.

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure, but the number 9,999,999,999 is larger than the maximum representable [signed integer in 32 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29#Common_integral_data_types). I don't know which datatypes are used to represent CSS values internally, or what are the upper limits of these value.

Comment: Hiding the `<label>`s using `text-indent` (or similar) is a common technique to hide them from visual users (who can work out the meaning of the input using visual cues) while preserving a label for (for example) screen reader users. Setting `visibility: hidden` and `display:none` will also hide the labels from screen reader users, so don't do that. You might find an `aria-label="whatever"` attribute on the input less objectionable, but `aria-label` has less user agent support than an offscreen positioning trick.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your `.hide` rules with something like Bootstrap's [`sr-only`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-screen-readers):

```
.hide {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add position relative to your form element and z-index:999 on it then it will be fine.